# mysql trigger to update a record on same table after insert

Tags: mysql

Is this logic valid for a mysql trigger? (AFTER INSERT)
Basically, I want to update a record in the same table, column DateTimeRecorded=NOW() if the DateTimeRecorded which was just inserted has a value='0000-00-00 00:00:00' based on the Object_ID (autoincremented) that has just been inserted (that's why i'm using AFTER INSERT).

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_OBJECTS
      AFTER INSERT ON Objects
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
    IF OLD.DateTimeRecorded='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
          UPDATE Objects set OLD.DateTimeRecorded=NOW() 
          WHERE OLD.OBJECT_ID=NEW.OBJECT_ID;
        END IF;
      END;
```

Am I doing this correctly? In other words, I need to make sure the DateTimeRecorded has value of `NOW()` vs. `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

Comment: You can not update/insert on the same table where the trigger is running.

Comment: What is a workaround to solve this issue?